# Como pegar valores de uma session e descarregar em variáveis?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Fiz essa classe:

```
public class ConexaoParametrosTFV
{
    public ConexaoParametrosTFV()
    {
        if ((SessaoUtil.Recuperar("ConexaoTFV") == null))
        {
            AgaxturCmsEntities db = new AgaxturCmsEntities();

            var resultado = (from a in db.TbClientes
                             where a.CdCliente == 1 && a.Ativo == "S"
                             select new {
                                 a.CultureTripoint,
                                 a.LoginTripoint,
                                 a.SenhaTripoint,
                                 a.SalesChannelTripoint,
                                 a.DepartmentIdTripoint,
                                 a.EntityIdTripoint }).First();

            SessaoUtil.SalvarSession("ConexaoTFV", "resultado");
        }
    }
}
```

Preciso agora em outra classe, pegar tudo que tiver carregado na session e descarregar em seis variáveis.
Como eu faço isso?

Comment: `SessaoUtil.SalvarSession("ConexaoTFV", "resultado");` parece estar errado, `"resultado"` é uma string, e não faz referência à variável `resultado`.

Comment: nem atentei para isso

Comment: Salva o objeto na session, depois seta cada variável com o valor de cada propriedade do objeto.

Comment: Essa é minha dúvida. Como eu faço isso? Esse é o motivo do meu post.

Comment: var recuperando = SessaoUtil.Recuperar("ConexaoFTV");
var1 = recuperando.var1;
var2 = recuperando.var2;

Comment: Não funciona assim

Comment: em vez de usar var, use dynamic, quando vc usa var ele cria um anonymous e voce nao saberá na hora de recuperar qual é o tipo do seu objeto. Use dynamic na hora de capturar o resultado do TbClientes

Comment: @Roger: agora que percebi que o OP está usando objetos de classe anônima. Ainda assim, não recomendaria usar `dynamic`, e sim uma classe para representar o objeto.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo concordo 100% contigo mas isso abriria um precedente para que ele tivesse que declarar uma nova classe para cada consulta diferente nas Views.

Comment: Sim, é o que acontece por exemplo com classes de ViewModel e DomainModel. Cada um possui uma classe representativa, e isso faz o projeto ficar mais consistente.

Comment: @Roger: mesmo discordando de você, poderia adicionar uma resposta com sua solução... ela é uma solução válida. =D

Comment: @MiguelAngelo, a solução do iuri faz o que eu sugeri, deve funcionar. Eu concordo que o ideal é usar uma ViewModel para todas e quaisquer views do MVC mas já que o amiguinho não está usando eu costumo ser pragmático em dar a solução em linha com a cabeça dele. :)

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você precisa corrigir essa linha em seu código:

```
//SessaoUtil.SalvarSession("ConexaoTFV", "resultado");
SessaoUtil.SalvarSession("ConexaoTFV", resultado);
```

Depois recupere com sua classe, se estiver OK você conseguirá fazer isso:

```
var resultado = SessaoUtil.Recuperar("ConexaoTFV") as dynamic;
string login = resultado.LoginTripoint;
```

Faça isso para o restante de suas propriedades da query.

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer assim.

```
string teste = HttpContext.Current.Session["NOME_SESSION"];
```

Comment: Assim, eu trago os dados para a variável. var teste = SessaoUtil.Recuperar("ConexaoTFV"); O que eu não consigo é ir atribuindo as variáveis, os campos, por exemplo: culture = test.CultureTripoint e assim por diante. Ele não reconhece o dado na variável: CultureTripoint, ou seja, não consigo pegar esse cara dentro da var ou session.

Comment: O que você tem que fazer é um cast na session e converter ela pro mesmo objeto que está gravando. ex:
se você quer uma propriedade da classe ConexaoTFV:
`código`
ConexaoTFV con = new ConexaoTFV();
HttpContext.Current.Session["NOME_SESSION"] = con;
con.CultureTripoint = "Cultura Escolhida".
Para ler a session:
ConexaoTFV teste = (ConexaoTFV)HttpContext.Current.Session["NOME_SESSION"];

teste.CultureTripoint

Comment: ou então tente string teste =((ConexaoTFV)HttpContext.Current.Session["NOME_SESSION"]).CulteureTripoint;

Comment: Criei uma classe com get e set e carreguei os atributos dela no construtor onde crio a minha session e carreguei a session com esses valores. No outro lado, instancio a classe e agora consigo atribuir às variáveis os valores dos atributos da mesma. Funcionou. Obrigado a todos. Ah! sim, fiz o cast que o Marco sugeriu, claro, pois sem ele não funcionava mesmo. Assim: var _conexao = (ConexaoTFV)SessaoUtil.Recuperar("ConexaoTFV"); ConexaoTFV é a minha classe POCO.

Answer (score 0):

Não tinha percebido, mas graças ao comentário do @Roger, percebi que você está usando objetos de classes anônimas.

Não é possível ler as propriedades de uma classe anônima fora do método que a criou. Isso acontece pois a definição da classe anônima se perde no método que a criou.

Nesses casos o recomendável é criar uma classe com propriedades para representar o objeto. A classe anônima não é uma boa alternativa neste caso, em que o objeto é usado por mais de um método.

**Crie uma classe para representar o objeto assim:**

```
class MinhaClasse
{
     public string CultureTripoint { get; set; }
     public string LoginTripoint { get; set; }
     public string SenhaTripoint { get; set; }
     public string SalesChannelTripoint { get; set; }
     public string DepartmentIdTripoint { get; set; }
     public string EntityIdTripoint { get; set; }
}
```

**E na sua query faça assim:**

```
       var resultado = (from a in db.TbClientes
                         where a.CdCliente == 1 && a.Ativo == "S"
                         select new MinhaClasse {
                             CultureTripoint = a.CultureTripoint,
                             LoginTripoint = a.LoginTripoint,
                             SenhaTripoint = a.SenhaTripoint,
                             SalesChannelTripoint = a.SalesChannelTripoint,
                             DepartmentIdTripoint = a.DepartmentIdTripoint,
                             EntityIdTripoint = a.EntityIdTripoint }).First();

        SessaoUtil.SalvarSession("ConexaoTFV", "resultado");
```

**Depois para recuperar os valores:**

```
var meuObjeto = (MinhaClasse)SessaoUtil.Recuperar("ConexaoTFV");
```

Comment: Isso já fiz e funcionou. Uma pergunta aos mestres. Eu tenho no construtor da classe a minha session. Eu sempre instancio a classe para gerar o construtor. Depois crio uma var do tipo da classe e atribuo os valores da session a esta var. Está correto? Ou ao invés de duas linhas, só preciso de uma? Tenho mesmo que instanciar a classe por causa do construtor ou basta invocar a session que será feito? Faço assim:ConexaoParametrosTFV conexao = new ConexaoParametrosTFV();
                var _conexao = (ConexaoTFV)SessaoUtil.Recuperar("ConexaoTFV");

Comment: Se o objeto estiver armazenado na Session, então não será necessário criar outro. Essa linha basta: `var _conexao = (ConexaoTFV)SessaoUtil.Recuperar("ConexaoTFV");`